# resume the state when we minimise the app using android

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I am using webview android app and open the particular page from the app. After that when we minimize the app and open it again it start from the home page. What i want is, when we open the minimize app, it should resume from the page which was opened before minimizing it.

For this, I am using this code:-

```
 public void onResume() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onResume:");
    super.onResume();
}
```

also, I tried this code:-

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

}

but it's not working